# How can i know how much RAM can i upgrade my laptop?

Tags: upgrade, ram, acer

I have a Acer (Aspire E1-431) laptop. which I would like to increase the RAM. Ideally I would like to have 4Gb but I have no idea how to check if hardware could support this extension.

```
mchandru@mchandru-Aspire-E1-431:~$ sudo lshw
mchandru-aspire-e1-431    
    description: Notebook
    product: Aspire E1-431 (Type1Sku0)
    vendor: Acer
    version: V1.26TD3
    serial: NXM8VSI0013090643D7620
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: chassis=notebook family=Type1Family sku=Type1Sku0 uuid=12A88214-5326-4676-B2C5-089E018CBDB9
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: EA40_HC
       vendor: Acer
       physical id: 0
       version: Type2 - Board Version
       serial: NBM8V110013090643D7620
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.26TD3
          date: 02/21/2013
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 4032KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 1331MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm epb xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-through instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: a
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: internal write-through unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: b
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 8
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: internal write-through data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 18
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: RMT3010EC58E8F1333
             vendor: Unknown
             physical id: 0
             serial: 40AF5724
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: Empty
             vendor: Empty
             physical id: 1
             serial: Empty
             slot: DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:27 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:90604000-9060400f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:90609000-906093ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.10.0-35-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.10
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:90600000-90603fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:90500000-905fffff ioport:90400000(size=1048576)
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:24 memory:90500000-9050ffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
                logical name: enp4s0f2
                version: 0a
                serial: 08:9e:01:8c:bd:b9
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90404000-90404fff memory:90400000-90403fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:90608000-906083ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.10.0-35-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.10
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Wireless interface
                      product: Moto E (4) Plus
                      vendor: MediaTek
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@2:1.3
                      version: ff.ff
                      serial: ZH33B28HHX
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=rndis_host maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:25 ioport:3088(size=8) ioport:3094(size=4) ioport:3080(size=8) ioport:3090(size=4) ioport:3060(size=32) memory:90607000-906077ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:90605000-906050ff ioport:3040(size=32)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD3200BPVT-2
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1A01
             serial: WD-WXG1E82SXD91
             size: 298GiB (320GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=5764d4c7
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: fc25-dbc3
                size: 498MiB
                capacity: 500MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-08-16 01:59:08 filesystem=ntfs label=System Reserved modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: 3495fa12-711d-e441-bc11-d2fa59784434
                size: 199GiB
                capacity: 199GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-08-16 01:59:23 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
           *-volume:2
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                size: 3905MiB
                capacity: 3905MiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 3905MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:3
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                logical name: /
                logical name: /var/lib/docker/plugins
                logical name: /var/lib/docker/aufs
                version: 1.0
                serial: 8fe75655-ec9a-4970-8af1-b09e771bff31
                size: 94GiB
                capacity: 94GiB
                capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-08-15 18:34:29 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2017-10-01 23:51:44 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2017-10-01 23:51:50 state=mounted
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s29u1u3
       serial: 06:48:f2:8a:33:fa
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.2 link=yes multicast=yes
mchandru@mchandru-Aspire-E1-431:~$
```

Comment: Use Google - http://www.memorystock.com/memory/AcerAspireE1431Series.html and http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-e1-431-4404

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way to check max RAM capacity is with dmidecode:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

The output will look something like this:

```
Handle 0x000A, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 2 GB    <---- look for this line
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2
```

...or even better `sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep Max`

Comment: I'd be a little cautious about the "Maximum Capacity", as that may be more theoretical limits, than what one might be able to actually put into a computer, especially a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in a terminal (ctrl-alt-t to start one) run the command:

```
sudo dmidecode | more
```

and look at the "Physical Memory Array", which should tell you the maximum capacity and the number of devices for system memory.

Answer (score 0):

Going to the [Accer website](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support) you can search your device by its serial number which in your output is in the first section `serial: NXM8VSI0013090643D7620`. On the next page go to **Product Details** then enter your serial number again and you will be taken to the specs for that laptop. It shows that your max memory is 8 GB.

Comment: Thank your for response. It means i can upgrade upto 8GB in my laptop ??

Comment: @Chandru if 8G is the max, and you only have 2 slots in your laptop, make sure that you install equal size RAM... ie: 4G x 2, so that memory interleaving can work correctly.